# System architecture : design considerations. Java vs Django vs RoR

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, django, spring, architecture

I'd like to designing new web application with few requirements and considering which language/framework I should choose.

Requirements:

- Web based solution (web UI and backed)
- Fast deployment and setup <- by this I mean just run by single command, 
  no configuration needed for total beginner. Similar to
  Jenkins

  java -jar jenkins.war

  or Gerrit.
- Some kind of que to run tasks asynchronously.
- No code protection

Due to the fact that I want to be simple to run and deploy (without initial configuration needed) I am considering using **Java EE/Spring** framework. 
Initially I was considering **Django or RoR** since deploy is pretty easy and development is way faster than Java but those 
frameworks need some kind of scheduling framework like **Celery + some kind of broker** so additional configuration is needed. 
I am not limited to any language,(besides PHP since I just do not like it :P)

If any of you have any thoughts about my design and want to share let's do it.

Thanks a lot for any kind of question/ answers.

Comment: Off-topic. But it sounds like you're rewriting (part of) [fossil](https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

Comment: Try Java + Spring Boot

Comment: @11thdimension I'm intensely thinking about Java but I can see one big disadvantage of this choice - development time. Django or RoR are strictly for web based aps and development, testing and deployment is just fast . We cannot say that about Java.

Comment: @Rafal That characterization is nonsense if you're using modern Java tools (from the last few years or so).

Comment: The answer is quite simple: If you want to get quick results, pick the language and framework where you have the most experience. If you don't have any experience in RoR, it doesn't matter how well it is suited for an application, you won't get good and fast results with it.

Comment: @chrylis I cannot agree with this.For one of the projects I am using java + spring and for another one Django, and I can easily say that working with Django is way faster.
@ dunni is not that simple as it may looks like. Let's assume that I know RoR, Django and Java equally and want's only others people opinion.Let's also do not assume that RoR, Java or Django are only choices. Scala, node.js also could be used.

Comment: You trying to start a flame war son? This is too broad and opinion based a question to be helpful. Perhaps entertaining, but not helpful.

Comment: @ C dot StrifeVII not really :P. That was not my intention. I will close this question since this slowly going out of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very open question and there is really no right answer for it. Rails is really great framework for web development, there are gems basically for everything but deployment is not as straightforward as `java -jar` and also it does not shine that much when you have SPA on the frontend.

If you're planning to build Single Page Application with one of the modern frameworks you may want to consider Spring Boot. Main benefits:

- very ops friendly (`java -jar`), metrics, health checks
- whole application config just in one file
- great MVC framework for exposing REST endpoints
- implementing tasks running in background is trivial.
- few programming languages to choose from: Java, Groovy, Kotlin.

Grails 3 looks also promising but since I haven't used it yet I can only suggest having a look.

Comment: It was intended to be wide and open question. I'm open for any suggestion and I will take into consideration your answer as any others. I'm just collecting pros and cons. Thanks for tip